# PostgreSQL logical replication not working after added a new table to publication

Tags: postgresql, subscription, logical-replication

I am new to PostgreSQL logical replication.
I did test, after I added a new table to a publication, I found the replication didn't work, until I re-created subscription, I am sure it's not the best practice to re-create subscription, could you please advise how make subscriber apply transactions for the new table?

Test as below:

1. Create the first table on primary and replicate side:

   ```
    create table rep_test (a int primary key, b int);
   ```
2. Create publication on primary side:

   ```
    CREATE PUBLICATION rep_test_pub FOR table public.rep_test;
   ```
3. Create subscription on replicate side:

   ```
    CREATE SUBSCRIPTION rep_test_sub CONNECTION 'host=XXX port=5432 dbname=rocket user=XXX password=XXX' PUBLICATION rep_test_pub WITH (copy_data = false);
   ```
4. Test the replication, the replication works.
   Primary side:

   ```
    insert into rep_test values (1, 1); insert into rep_test values (2, 1);
   ```

   Replicate:

   ```
    select * from rep_test;

    *---*---*
    | a | b |
    *---*---*
    | 1 | 1 |
    | 2 | 1 |
    *---*---*
   ```
5. Create a new table on both primary and replicate side

   ```
    create table rep_test (a int primary key, b text);
   ```
6. Add new table to publication on primary side

   ```
    alter publication rep_test_pub add table public.rep_test2;
   ```
7. Test the replication, the replication is not working.
   Primary:

   ```
    insert into rep_test values (3, 1); insert into rep_test2 values (1,'text');
   ```

Replicate:

```
    select * from rep_test;

    *---*---*
    | a | b |
    *---*---*
    | 1 | 1 |
    | 2 | 1 |
    | 3 | 1 |
    *---*---*

    select * from rep_test2;
```

Note: No data in `rep_test2`, the replication didn't replicate `rep_test2`.

8. Reboot replicate postgres, the replication still not working.
9. Drop and re-create subscription, the replication works.

Primary:

```
truncate table rep_test; truncate table rep_test2;
```

Replicate:

```
drop subscription rep_test_sub;
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION rep_test_sub CONNECTION 'host=XXX port=5432 dbname=rocket user=XXX password=XXX' PUBLICATION rep_test_pub WITH (copy_data = false);
```

Primary:

```
insert into rep_test values (1, 1); insert into rep_test2 values (1, 'text');
```

Replicate:

```
select * from rep_test;select * from rep_test2;
 
*---*---*
| a | b |
*---*---*
| 1 | 1 |
*---*---*
(1 row)

*---*-----*
| a | b   | 
*---*-----*
| 1 | text|
*---*-----*
(1 row)
```

The replication works after re-created subscription.

Could you please advise is there another way to make subscriber apply transactions to the new table?

BTW, my version:

> PostgreSQL 12.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39), 64-bit

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

The new table is not replicated until you do REFRESH PUBLICATION on the subscription.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersubscription.html

> REFRESH PUBLICATION Fetch missing table information from publisher.
>   This will start replication of tables that were added to the
>   subscribed-to publications since the last invocation of REFRESH
>   PUBLICATION or since CREATE SUBSCRIPTION.

Comment: Thanks you so much, I missed that.

Comment: refresh not working for me I don't know why,only erase all data and recreate subscription

Comment: @arisyang Please accept the answer if this answered your question

Answer (score 0):

Being a little precise to jjanes answer, you just need to run below command on subscriber database after that data will be replicated to subscribed table.

ALTER SUBSCRIPTION sub_name REFRESH PUBLICATION;